# How to show/hide table onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show/hide table `#block-views-apk_user_tracker_page-block_1 .views-table` onclick link "NOTIFICATIONS" that's within div `#block-views-apk_user_tracker_page-block_1 .views-header`. I've tried different scripts but none of them worked, they all seem to be for id's or list, not classes and tables.

Here's the code, it's for site notifications, facebook style.

```html
<div class="view-header">
      <img src="/photos/led_red.gif"> <a href="/user/3/newforumposts">NOTIFICATIONS (6)</a>    </div>
  
  
  
      <div class="view-content">
      <table class="views-table cols-6">
    <thead>
    <tr>
              <th class="views-field views-field-title">
                  </th>
              <th class="views-field views-field-last-comment-timestamp">
                  </th>
              <th class="views-field views-field-new-comments">
                  </th>
          </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
          <tr class="odd views-row-first">
                  <td class="views-field views-field-title">
            <a href="/node/3955">TITLE 1</a>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-last-comment-timestamp">
            24/05/2015 - 03:56          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-new-comments">
            <a href="/node/3955?page=14#new">1 new</a>          </td>
              </tr>
          <tr class="even">
                  <td class="views-field views-field-title">
            <a href="/node/10452">TITLE 2</a>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-last-comment-timestamp">
            24/05/2015 - 03:24          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-new-comments">
            <a href="/node/10452#new">2 new</a>          </td>
              </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="views-field views-field-title">
            <a href="/node/10445">TITLE 3</a>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-last-comment-timestamp">
            24/05/2015 - 03:21          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-new-comments">
            <a href="/node/10445?page=2#new">1 new</a>          </td>
              </tr>
          <tr class="even">
                  <td class="views-field views-field-title">
            <a href="/node/3871">ANOTHER TITLE</a>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-last-comment-timestamp">
            24/05/2015 - 03:17          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-new-comments">
            <a href="/node/3871?page=8#new">1 new</a>          </td>
              </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
                  <td class="views-field views-field-title">
            <a href="/node/10470">Yet another title</a>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-last-comment-timestamp">
            24/05/2015 - 03:14          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-new-comments">
            <a href="/node/10470#new">1 new</a>          </td>
              </tr>
          <tr class="even views-row-last">
                  <td class="views-field views-field-title">
            <a href="/node/10469">and another</a>          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-last-comment-timestamp">
            24/05/2015 - 03:13          </td>
                  <td class="views-field views-field-new-comments">
            <a href="/node/10469?page=1#new">1 new</a>          </td>
              </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
```

Comment: OK I made it work with this jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/2237 but now's another problem cause I'm using module that's refreshing block in wchich this code is and after refresh this script is not working anymore I think it has to do that it's only loaded on page load once...

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add an extra `id` or `class`.

```
$(function() {
     $(".view-header").click("a", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(".view-header").siblings(".view-content").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: If `view-header` has several `<a>`, it is needed to have `id` or `class`

Comment: Right, but there is only one `a` inside `.view-header`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to hide / show the div with class **`view-table`** when user cliks on

You have to add a **`class`** or **`id`** to you **`<a href="/user/3/newforumposts">`**, like this :

```
<div class="view view-apk-user-tracker-page view-id-apk_user_tracker_page view-display-id-block_1 view-dom-id-6">
  <div class="view-header">
    <img src="/photos/led_red.gif">
    <a href="/user/3/newforumposts" class="notif isShown">NOTIFICATIONS (6)</a>
  </div>

    <!-- Following the code -->
```

And you will be able to achieve your aim with this js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#block-views-apk_user_tracker_page-block_1 .views-header .notif').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('isShown')) {
      $(this).removeClass('isShown');
      $('#block-views-apk_user_tracker_page-block_1 .views-table').fadeOut(250);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('isShown');
      $('#block-views-apk_user_tracker_page-block_1 .views-table').fadeIn(250);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: yes but it's important to include #block-views-apk_user_tracker_page-block_1 because I've got plenty of views tables on my page.

Comment: I have applied changes

Comment: It's not working I'm guessing it's because drupal 6 only has jquery 1.2.6 maybe this function is from newer version..

Comment: no it just goes to the link target and when I put display:none in css the table doesn't appear onclick

Comment: how about doing it in javascript instead of jquery?